# How to remove toolbar in rhomobile production build?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhomobile, rhodes

I am trying to remove toolbar entirely in rhomobile 4.0.0 but `@@toolbar = nil` property is not working in rhomobile 4.0.0 production build.

Comment: So, you've removed the comment in the application.rb file in your project and now the 

  @@toolbar = nil

line is executed but you still se the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Yes, I have removed but i am still able to see navigation bar.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project before building it?

Answer (score 0):

Building a new project with RhoMobile v5.1.1 (the latest available at this moment) or with RhoMobile Suite v4.0.0 (that is nearly two years old but is the one included in the original question), the navigation bar disappears when you uncomment the `@@toolbar = nil` line in the `application.rb` in the `/app/` folder of your project:

```
require 'rho/rhoapplication'

class AppApplication < Rho::RhoApplication
  def initialize
    # Tab items are loaded left->right, @tabs[0] is leftmost tab in the tab-    bar
    # Super must be called *after* settings @tabs!
    @tabs = nil
    #To remove default toolbar uncomment next line:
    @@toolbar = nil
    super

    # Uncomment to set sync notification callback to /app/Settings/sync_notify.
    # Rho::RhoConnectClient.setObjectNotification("/app/Settings/sync_notify")
    Rho::RhoConnectClient.setNotification('*', "/app/Settings/sync_notify", '')

  end
end
```

This is the original application, as scafolded by RhoMobile (with the navigation bar) running on an Android device:

[image: This is the original application, as scafolded by RhoMobile (with the navigation bar)]

And here the same application uncommenting the `@@toolbar = nil` line:
[image: same application uncommenting the <code>@@toolbar = nil</code> line]

Comment: I am asking for Rhomobile v4.0.0 not for  RhoMobile v5.1.1

Comment: The answer is the same testing on the older release. I've recovered an old VM with RhoMobile v4.0.0 (it's about 2years old) and the behaviour is the same, uncommenting the @@toolbar = nil eliminates the navigation bar at the bottom of the device. I suggest you to check your setup, trying to re-install the rhodes gem. I've done my test on the RhoSimulator and on Android and the behaviour is the same correct one. Which OS are you testing on?

Comment: I've done a couple of test with RhoMobile v4.0.0 and Qt v4.7.4 [following the setup instruction in the old documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/guide/nativesdksetup#setup-for-windows-desktop) and everything worked as expected. I've used Visual Studio 2008. I've done another test with RhoMobile v5.1.1, Qt v5.1.1 and Visual Studio 2008 and I had no issue. Can you please double check your setup (Visual Studio version, Qt library version, etc.)?